# Spring Data MongoOperations: Not able to remove sub-document in array with pull method

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

Following is the structure of my MongoDB document `userActivity`.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5e49569f93e956eeb28eb8a6"),
  "userId" : "123",
  "likes" : {
      "videos" : [ 
          {
              "_id" : "abc",
              "title" : "This video is part of test setup",
          }
      ]
   }
}
```

I am using Spring Data `MongoOperations` to manipulate MongoDB collections. And below is the code to remove a video from `videos` array in `likes` sub-document. I have tried to first filter the document as per the user's `userId`. And then apply filter to `update` function as per `videoId`.

```
public UpdateResult removeVideoLike(String videoId, String userId) {
  Query queryUser = Query.query( Criteria.where("userId").is(userId) );
  Query queryVideo = Query.query( Criteria.where("id").is(videoId) );
  Update update = new Update().pull("likes.videos", queryVideo );
  return mongoOperations.updateFirst( queryUser , update, UserActivity.class );
}
```

This runs without errors but the entry is not removed. The `UpdateResult` has following values

> matchedCount = 1
>   modifiedCount = 0
>   upsertedId = null

I am confused if it is able to match the entry in the array, why it is not removing it? What I am missing?

Comment: Which version of spring-data-mongodb are you using? I tried on current master and everything works as expected.

Comment: @ChristophStrobl I am using `spring-data-mongodb-2.2.1.RELEASE`.  So the code I have posted is working at your end?

Comment: I was using current 3.0 snapshot and tried 2.2.x as well - both worked. Can you check if the `queryUser` returns more than a single result? In that case `updateFirst` uses the first one to perform the update upon and if `likes.videos` already is empty, `modifiedCount` is set to zero since nothing changed.

Comment: @ChristophStrobl there is only one document in the collection. Can you share your code as well comparing them might help.

Comment: sure. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/commit/35214b9dd5a0cd9c9e7eae9a9cea54beb9e55bed

Comment: The issue is just that you are not using the right field name. The statement `Criteria.where("id").is(videoId)` should be `Criteria.where("_id").is(videoId)`.

Comment: field names are mapped to the domain types as long as those can be resolved via the domain model.